# Android Billing null pointer exception next day

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, in-app-purchase, billing

I have an app with opportunity to buy in-app item.
And when I've downloaded this app and tried to buy the item - everything is ok - buying intent appears (then I canceled transaction). the issue is that intent appears only first day after downloading app - the next day I got the crash "null pointer exception" on line

```
  startIntentSenderForResult(pendingIntent.getIntentSender(),
       1001, new Intent(), Integer.valueOf(0), Integer.valueOf(0),
       Integer.valueOf(0));
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: unfortently  it's appears only on downloaded copy, I cant reprodyce issue locally. so i doesn't recognize which object is null. but look i shouldn't pass null object to the method. because all i passed sucesfully used in code below

Comment: Could you post the log or stacktrace?

Comment: looks it was a bug, i've created new product in console and issue disappeared

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks it was a bug, i've created new product in console and issue disappeared

btw, you can faced with the similar issue in case you forgot to [consume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38540582/android-consume-a-product-after-purchase-in-app-billing) product